# Generating permutations from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I tried to port a function that generates permutations from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838933/1905958)  to PHP and I came out with the following:

```
function recurse($s, $arrs, $k) {
    if ($k === count($arrs)) {
        echo $s.' ';
    } else {
        foreach ($arrs[$k] as $o) {
            recurse($s.$o, $arrs, $k + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

which gives me the correct output

```
137 138 147 148 237 238 247 248
```

Now I want to have the output  as an array and not as a string, but after the edit for some reason I get wrong results:

```
function generatePermutations($s, $arrs, $k) {
    if ($k === count($arrs)) {
        print_r($s);
    } else {
        foreach ($arrs[$k] as $o) {
            $s[] = $o;
            generatePermutations($s, $arrs, $k + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
)
```

This is the input for both functions

```
$in = array( array(1, 2), array(3, 4), array(7, 8) );
recurse("", $in, 0);
generatePermutations(array(), $in, 0);
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use $s[] = $o; in your recursive function, it will slice your array for every digit.
You can add a "result" parameter, which will hold your resultset as an array.
Notice the & sign. Without it, the parameter is not "writable", only "readable".

```
$in = array( array(1, 2), array(3, 4), array(7, 8) );
$result = array();
generatePermutations("", $in, 0, $result);
print_r($result);

function generatePermutations($s, $arrs, $k, &$result) {
    if ($k === count($arrs)) {
        $result[] = $s; 
    } else {
        foreach ($arrs[$k] as $o) {
            generatePermutations($s.$o, $arrs, $k + 1, $result);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 137
    [1] => 138
    [2] => 147
    [3] => 148
    [4] => 237
    [5] => 238
    [6] => 247
    [7] => 248
)
```

Edit : Modification to get Robotex's expected output :

```
$in = array( array(1, 2), array(3, 4), array(7, 8) );
$result = array();
$s = array();
generatePermutations($s, $in, 0, $result);
print_r($result);

function generatePermutations(&$s, $arrs, $k, &$result) {
    if ($k === count($arrs)) {
        array_push($result, $s);
    } else {
        foreach ($arrs[$k] as $o) {
            array_push($s, $o);
            generatePermutations($s, $arrs, $k + 1, $result);
            array_pop($s);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 8
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 8
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I am trying to do, actually what I meant in my problem is that I want each result to be an array where the elements are the digits/items
ex:
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 7 )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 8 )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 )
etc.

Comment: Ok thanks for giving expected result. I edited my post to get that.